# Сортировка в yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Мне нужно сделать сортировку.
Средствами yii2, согласно документации делается так .

```
function actionIndex()
{
    $sort = new Sort([
        'attributes' => [
            'age',
            'name' => [
                'asc' => ['first_name' => SORT_ASC, 'last_name' => SORT_ASC],
                'desc' => ['first_name' => SORT_DESC, 'last_name' => SORT_DESC],
                'default' => SORT_DESC,
                'label' => 'Name',
            ],
        ],
    ]);

    $models = Article::find()
        ->where(['status' => 1])
        ->orderBy($sort->orders)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
         'models' => $models,
         'sort' => $sort,
    ]);
}
```

Работает нормально. Но , мне нужно немного сложнее запрос сделать.
Вот такой запрос

```
SELECT * , (object_info.price / ( SELECT price_type.course FROM price_type WHERE price_type.id = object_info.price_type_id)) AS real_price FROM object_info ORDER BY real_price
```

Так вот как его туда прописать строкой запроса ??

Пытался вот так

```
$query = ObjectInfo::find();
        $sort = new Sort([
            'attributes' => [
                'created_at',
                'price' => [
                    $query->select(['*', 'real_price' => 'SELECT * , 
                    (object_info.price / ( SELECT price_type.course FROM price_type WHERE price_type.id = object_info.price_type_id)) 
                    AS real_price 
                    FROM object_info 
                    ORDER BY real_price']),
                    'asc' => ['real_price' => SORT_ASC],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

Не работает, пишет что real_price не найдет в таблице. Все так, вот такому определению просто имя задано

```
(object_info.price / ( SELECT price_type.course FROM price_type WHERE price_type.id = object_info)) AS real_price
```

Как тогда сделать?

Comment: Где именно прописать??

Answer (score 1):

Укажите select в конструкторе запроса, класс `yii\data\Sort` не поддерживает каких либо конструкций с запросами.

```
$sort = new Sort([
    'attributes' => [
        'created_at',
        'price' => [
            'asc' => ['real_price' => SORT_ASC],
        ],
    ],
]);

$query = ObjectInfo::find()
     ->select(['*', 'real_price' => 'object_info.price / ( SELECT price_type.course FROM price_type WHERE price_type.id = object_info.price_type_id)')
     ->orderBy($sort->orders);

$models = $query->all();
```

Comment: Спасибо, делал раньше так же, но ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax. Суть в том, что в ->select(['*', 'real_price' =>.. Так можно делать? так как real_price это не название поля, а просто название части запроса , после AS

Comment: А если убрать в 'real_price' => 'SELECT * , (object_info.price... Первый SELECT , то ошибок нет, но и сортирует просто по колонке price, а не по real_price (

Comment: Да можно указывать псевдонимы в качестве ключей. Убрал лишнее в конструкторе. Вы вообще ваш sql код проверяли?

Comment: Да в mysql все работало верно. Спасибо, Вы правильно решили, я просто при выводе не указал $models в foreach ) А потом уже переделал, чтобы через dataProvider работало